# How can I choose the value of output neurons for the hidden layer of tf.keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to Keras and starting with this code from tf tutorial :

```
# choosing the layers of my models 
model = keras.Sequential([ # the sequential model of Keras library 
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)), # the first input layer
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),# the hidden layer 
    keras.layers.Dense(10)# output layers and 10 corresponds to the number of used classes 
])
```

I wonder what the value 128 is? and how it was calculated?

Comment: the `128` is the number of nodes of that layer. to put it simple let's take the case of classification :
in the last layer you have 10 which is the number of the output classes in the same way the hidden layer classifies the items -theorically- in 128 classes and then passes these "classes" to the output layer which kind of regroup them in the 10 possible classes.

Comment: I understand the part related to the input and output layers, but I could not understand how to choose the optimal number of nodes (neurons) in the hidden layer, for example, the range or is it the mean(input, output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not calculated, it's a hyperparameter (a parameter that isn't estimated by the data, but selected by *you* prior to running the model). It essentially determines the complexity of the model. The more neurons, the more complex relationships it can model in the data.

Answer (score 2):

`128` is a hyper parameter which is the number of nodes in your second to last layer.

It isn't calculated, you can change it to whatever you want, try `[18,32,64...etc]`. The larger you make it the slower your training will be; however your model might be more accurate since there are more nodes to capture the signal of your dataset.